# Hibernate Synchronizer

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

i want to install hibernate synchronizer to synchronize the mapping and the essential files for hibernate like actions hbml ...
This is for eclipse indigo, but the plug-in available is for hibernate 2.x.

So i don't know if there is an hibernate synchronizer plug-in for hibernate 3.x
I try to copy the hibernate synchronizer [3.x project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernatesynch/) to the eclipse path (plugins and features) but it's not useful. i don't have any modification in eclipse ..

As well as we don't have a context.xml file in this zip file we cannot install it through eclipse with "install a new software". Also, we don't have a direct link for fetching it with "install a new software"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is another solution which make you to do all the mapping and the synchronization of hibernate. 
We have jboss tools.

for Eclipse indigo : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools-indigo

for Eclipse Helios  : http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools-1

to install, just drag to your running Eclipse the *install* icon

jboss tools contains :

- Cloud Tools
- ModeShape Tools
- Seam Dev Tools
- Visual Web Tools
- jBPM Tools
- Hibernate Tools
- JSF Tools
- Struts Tools
- JBoss Portal Tools
- Birt Plugin Integration
- Drools Tools
- Eclipse Guvnor Tools
- Smooks
- BPMN Convert
- JMX
- JBoss BPEL

Answer (score 1):

if you want use hibernate synchronizer for hibernate 3, download this zip file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernatesynch/files/latest/download)

And just copy **plugins** and **features** in the path of your Eclipse home